# Restore previous window size with Spectacle

Tags: macos, finder, window-manager

With Spectacle, is there a way to restore a window to its original size after moving and sizing it? Some of the commercial alternatives offer this feature, but it doesn't seem to be supported with Spectacle.

Answer (score 3):

You can undo window positions by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: That doesn't restore the previous window size.

Comment: @RHPT are you sure? I can't test this at the moment, but I swear it does.

Comment: You are right it does restore the previous window size. However, it does not work in Google Chrome, which is what I was using to test.

Comment: It doesn't restore a previous state, it's just "UNDO" function.

Comment: I found that you may have to do multiple `Cmd`+`Z` to get back all the way to where you want.